# How to test semaphores with PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, pthreads

I'm using The [Symfony Lock package](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-lock-component) to check if a class method can be executed

```php
if ($this->lock->acquire()) {
    $this->execute();
    $this->lock->release();
}
```

> **Important**: I'm not using the Symfony Framework, only the Lock component

I want to make a **test that asserts that the execution is locked when running in multiple threads**, but I have not found any documentation on how to achieve this.

Is it a good idea to use [pthreads](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)? If not, which is the best way to make this test?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the Lock Component documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html#usage

Information on the CommandTester : 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#testing-commands

Solution for PHPUnit test :

```
use Symfony\Component\Lock\Factory;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\Store\SemaphoreStore;

public function testLockIsSet()
{     
    // Create a new Semaphore lock with the same ID as the one that would be
    // created if you were running the command / class / process etc.
    $store = new SemaphoreStore();
    $factory = new Factory($store);
    $lock = $factory->createLock('lock-name-used-eg-generate-pdf');

    if ($lock->acquire()) {
        // In my use case I was running multiple commands to see if the lock
        // was working properly
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($this->command);

        // Try and run the command. The lock should already be set.
        $commandTester->execute(
            [
                'command'  => $this->command->getName()
            ]
        );

        // You could also use expectException() here for LogicException    
        $this->assertContains(
            'The command is already running in locked mode.',
            $commandTester->getDisplay()
        );

        $lock->release();
    }
}
```

Comment: For information, I tried something like this, but it seems the lock can't be release while unit testing, i had to delete `*.lock` files in `/tmp` directory to get it works.